# Automatically generate filename using bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

Let's assume i have such files:

```
out-1.avi
```

I want to have a piece of bash code which will give me the next filename for such list:

```
out-1.avi
out-2.avi
out-3.avi
etc.
```

**Edit** The thing i need to achieve is to get next filename for webcam recording script so it wont ovewrite!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the context, but the following loop contains all the elements you will need:-

```
n=0; while (($n < 10)); do ((++n)); echo name=out-$n.avi; done
```

This will list the first 10 files in your sequence.

After your edit, I see several answers.

A simple modification of my original loop would be:-

```
n=1; while [ -f out-$n.avi ]; do ((++n)); done; echo name=out-$n.avi
```

This will work well for a few files, but becomes increasingly inefficient as the number of files mounts into the hundreds.

A more efficient answer would be to save the latest file number in its own file:-

```
n=`line<avicount.text`; ((++n)); echo "$n">avicount.text; echo name=out-$n.avi
```

This script will generate a new name each time it is called, but relies on `avicount.text` remaining always in synchronisation with the files and names in use.

A better solution all round would be to use a time stamp instead of a sequence number:-

```
echo name=out-`date +%Y%M%d%H%m%S`.avi
```

This will give a unique name based on the second when the script is called, and it can be useful to have a file's creation time included in its name. This scheme also allows for files to be deleted, archived or otherwise moved at will, without affecting future file names.

Comment: That last one should probably be `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `seq` to generate the values, then `touch` to create the files.

```
for n in $(seq 1 5)
do
    touch out-${n}.avi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
LAST=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.avi" -type f -printf "%p\n" | sed -e s/.\\/out-//g -e s/.avi//g | sort -g | tail -1)
touch out-$(($LAST + 1)).avi
```

- The first line picks the last modified avi file in the directory (no recursive), and extract the number in it's name.
- Second line add 1 to the previous name and generate the file.

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work for me: for some reason in my (UK) collating sequence `sort` places `out-10.avi` before `out-1.avi`, and with 10 files the last always comes out as `out-9.avi`. If you put the `sed` command immediately after the `find`, then use `sort -g`, it should work.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have many files in the video directory (in which case this approach is not very efficient), this simple peace of code may help:

```
MAX=1000;
PREFIX="out-"
SUFFIX=".avi"

for i in `seq 1 $MAX` ; do
    file="${PREFIX}${i}${SUFFIX}"

    if [ ! -e $file ] ; then
        break;
    fi
done

# this is the next available file name
echo $file
```

Note that this script will fill any discontinuities in the order of the files, so if you are concerned with precise order or maybe want to consider an option to delete "unnecessary" files from the sequence, you may want to use a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 0):

The solution @jherran supplied should probably meet you needs.  If you just want the script to **give** you the next filename, rather than create it for you, change "touch" to "echo" at the end of his script.

However, this will get slower and slower as you add many files.  If you have a need for sequential numbers, you could just write the current number out to a file, then read it back in before writing your next file, write out the new number, and write out your file.  I've provided sample code to do that below.

However, if you don't need sequential numbers, and just want non-colliding filenames, date-stamps are pretty useful.  They sort as you'd expect, and if you don't time-travel, are monotonically increasing.

For an answer to to the question you asked (shell script to return the next value) based on my suggestion above of just using a counter file, here is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

if [ -f counter.txt ]; then
{
   VAL=`cat counter.txt`
   echo "out-$VAL.avi"
   VAL=`expr $VAL + 1`
   echo "$VAL" > counter.txt
   exit 0
}
fi
echo "out-1.avi"
echo "2" > counter.txt
exit 0
```

Or, if you want to go with my suggestion of date-stamps for uniqueness and sorting, just have your file writing program grab the output of this command:

```
 date +%F-%T
```

or whatever granularity of dates and times you find useful.  The above will give you something like this:

```
2014-12-01-16:41:33
```

Slap a ".avi" on the end and you have timestamped filenames, down to the second.